# all combination of x pow y in php

Tags: php, math, combinations

I have an array having three element `$base =`**`(#m, #f,#p)`**

I have a second array having any number of element like `$var = (s1, s2)`

Now i need to create all possible combinations depending only on the base array. The formula I found is `x pow y`.

In this example my base array has three element and `$var` has **2**, so  `pow(3, 2)` is ***9***. I need these nine combinations. i.e

```
#m#m #m#f #m#p
#f#m #f#f #f#p
#p#m #p#f #p#p
```

The number of elements in the 2nd array is in effect the length of the generated combinations. As in this example the length of the 2nd array is 2 so all generated strings have length 2.

Comment: All you need is a nested loop and a `n-D array`.

Comment: How does the second array relate to the first? I don't see how it is relevant.

Comment: @DaveRandom Consider second array with 3 values. The result will be a 3x3x3 array.

Comment: So the only thing that is relevant about the second array is the number of elements it contains?

Comment: 2nd array is infect the length of generated combination. As in this example length of 2nd array is 2 so all generated string have length 2

Comment: @GiantofaLannister what if 2nd array has 5 values, that is length of each generated value is five ?

Comment: A 5-D array is the best way to assign those values. `3x3x3x3x3`.

Comment: what's with the random `$` and `#` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a recursive function like this:

```
// input definition
$baseArray = array("#m", "#f", "#p");
$varArray = array("s1", "s2", "s3");

// call the recursive function using input
$result = recursiveCombinations($baseArray, sizeof($varArray));

// loop over the resulting combinations
foreach($result as $r){
    echo "<br />combination " . implode(",", $r);
}

// this function recursively generates combinations of #$level elements
// using the elements of the $base array
function recursiveCombinations($base, $level){
    $combinations = array();
    $recursiveResults = array();

    // if level is > 1, get the combinations of a level less recursively
    // for level 1 the combinations are just the values of the $base array
    if($level > 1){
        $recursiveResults = recursiveCombinations($base, --$level);
    }else{
        return $base;   
    }
    // generate the combinations
    foreach($base as $baseValue){
        foreach($recursiveResults as $recursiveResult){
            $combination = array($baseValue);
            $combination = array_merge($combination, (array)$recursiveResult);  
            array_push($combinations, $combination);
        }
    }
    return $combinations;
}
```

[Working codepad demo](http://codepad.org/WIE4jhrJ)

Comment: Perfect, I can see this working great for me. I will work on this and update it if found any issue. U R SUPERB :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $strs = Array("some", "thing", "here");
    $poss = Array(1, 2);
    $new = Array();
    for($i = 0; $i < pow(count($strs), count($poss)); $i++) {
        for($j = 0; $j < count($strs); $j++) {
            $new[$i] = $strs[($i%count($strs))] . " " . $strs[$j];
        }
    }
    print_r($new);
?>
```

Working [codepad](http://codepad.org/zoflKhoc) link(for given example).

## LINKS

- [pow(4, 3)](http://codepad.org/vfj9hXIu)
- [pow(4, 2)](http://codepad.org/1FywBmFV)
- [pow(3, 5)](http://codepad.org/kwCVrOgx)

Comment: if you change  $poss = Array(1, 2,3) , that is length became three, it should generate value of length three whereas this code is generating value of length two, irrespective of size of $poss

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, unless I misunderstood the question. If you use the OP's input you get 3 identical sets of 3 combinations.